# convert or least remove non-english/unwanted(non-ascii) values from pandas column or convert it to English characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have values like '<U+6B66>'... in my one column(company_name). Please suggest a robust method to remove or convert it to readable strings.

Comment: regex to remove `<.....>`?? `re.sub(r'\<[^)]*\>', '', st)`

Comment: If u are having pandas dataframe then you can use apply/map. Please add sample dataframe.

Comment: What's that U+6B66 represent ? Any emoji/symbol? If yes then we can map them.

Comment: these are company names in russian,chinese,japanese..

Comment: only below code works for me to remove such rows and the main issue here is data loss as most of the company_names are such ambiguous.


df.drop(df[df.company_name.str.contains(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]')].index, inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

try using `regex` and `encode`:

```
string_unicode = " xyz <U+6B66> Æ for \u200c ab 23#. "
string_encode = re.sub(r'\<[^)]*\>', '', string_unicode)
string_encode = string_encode.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

**string_encode:**

```
b' xyz   for  ab 23#. '
```

Comment: can you simulate the same for dataframe column??

Comment: above solution does not work for me..

Comment: Also is there a way I can convert above characters to Englisg(ascii)..????